# If $x^* (x)=0$ for all $x^* \in X^*$, then $x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X$ is any arbitrary vector space, and $X^*$ is its dual, is it true that if $x^* (x)=0$ for all $x^* \in X^*$, then $x=0$?

Comment: Is $X$ finite-dimensional or does it have an inner product? I don't think it matters for the result, but it makes the argument a lot simpler.

Comment: No, I don't think so, I'm trying to understand the construction of weak topology on $X$, and $X$ is supposed to be an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: I gather $X^*$ is just the space of linear functions $X\to \Bbb K$, is it not?

Comment: Yes, I mean just the space of linear functionals. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use Hahn-Banach theorem to prove it , we take x such that x $\neq$ 0 , we define a functional on $span(x)$ such that $f(x)=1$ for example ...

then there is an extention of $f$ in $X$ .

Comment: every vector space has a norm , (by axiom of choice we can prove that every vector space has a basis )

Comment: What is the dominating sublinear functional for the hypothesis of HBT? Is it $|f|$?

Comment: I mean $|f|$, but zero outside $span\{x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put my own answer here, expounding on Abderrahim Abdou's. We will use the second form of Hahn-Banach theorem (which can be found on Wikipedia). Suppose for contradiction that $x \neq 0$, then $\text{span}\{x\}$ is nontrivial, and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha$  for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ is a linear functional on $\text{span}\{x\}$. Consider the seminorm $g$ on $X$ where $g(y)=|f(y)|$ for $y \in \text{span}\{x\}$ and $0$ otherwise. Since $|f| \leq g $ in $\text{span} \{x\}$, then by Hahn-Banach theorem, $f$ extends to a linear function in whole of $X$, therefore, $f \in X^*$, but $f(x)=1 \neq 0$ which is a contradiction.